# A character operand was found in the %EVAL function and Apparent symbolic reference %macro not resolved?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have two errors in two SAS programs :

In program 1 the code can't read the expression 'IN' and in program 2 I want to store the modate of each date in a specific macro.

Program1:

```
%macro Execution;
  
%if ( %sysfunc(weekday(%sysfunc(today()))) in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) and
%sysfunc(day(%sysfunc(today()))) in (1, 2, 3) )
%then %do;
    %put "The program is running";
%end;
    %else %do ;
     %put " No execution necessary.";
     %end;
  %mend Execution ; 
  %Execution ;

ERROR:A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.
```

Program 2:

```
 proc sql;
    select
        case
            when libname = 'LS' and memname = 'CONTRAT' then datepart(modate)
            when libname = 'KO' and memname = 'TCHOBQ' then datepart(modate)
            else .
        end
    into :modified_CONTRAT, :modified_TCHOBQ
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname in ('LS', 'KO') and memname in ('CONTRAT', 'TCHOBQ');
quit;
%put %sysfunc(day(&modified_CONTRAT.)) ;
%put %sysfunc(day(&modified_TCHOBQ.)) ;

       %put %sysfunc(day(&modified_CONTRAT.)) ;
10
ERROR:39  
40         %put %sysfunc(day(&modified_TCHOBQ.)) ;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference MODIFIED_TCHOBQ not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference MODIFIED_TCHOBQ not resolved.
ERROR: Argument 1 to function DAY referenced by the %SYSFUNC or %QSYSFUNC macro function is not a number.
ERROR: Invalid arguments detected in %SYSCALL, %SYSFUNC, or %QSYSFUNC argument list.  Execution of %SYSCALL statement or %SYSFUNC 
       or %QSYSFUNC function reference is terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first program you do not appear to have told SAS that you want the macro processor to threat the string IN as being an operator instead of just normal text.  You can add options to the %MACRO statement to let it know that at least for this macro you want IN to be considered an operator and that you want to use comma as the delimiter between the values in the list.

```
%macro Execution /minoperator mindelimiter=',';
```

In the second program you do not take into account the possibility that the WHERE condition might not match any observations.  So you need to first set the macro variables to some default value before the SELECT statement so they will exist.  To write to two macro variables you need to select two values.

```
proc sql;
%let modified_CONTRAT=.;
%let modified_TCHOBQ=.;
select max(case when libname='LS' and memname='CONTRAT' then datepart(modate) end)
     , max(case when libname='LS' and memname='TCHOBQ' then datepart(modate) end)
into :modified_CONTRAT
   , :modified_TCHOBQ
from dictionary.tables
where libname in ('LS', 'KO') and memname in ('CONTRAT', 'TCHOBQ')
;
quit;
```

That will eliminate the error about the macro variables not existing.  To fix the fact that DICTIONARY.TABLES did not find the datasets you will need to check whether they actually exist or not.  And whether the librefs exist and are pointing to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

### Program 1

You need to enable the `in` operator, either as a system option or a macro option. Personally I enable this as a default system option in my SAS startup code.

```
%macro Execution / minoperator mindelimiter=',';
  
%if ( %sysfunc(weekday(%sysfunc(today()))) in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) and
%sysfunc(day(%sysfunc(today()))) in (1, 2, 3) )
%then %do;
    %put "The program is running";
%end;
    %else %do ;
     %put " No execution necessary.";
     %end;
  %mend Execution ; 
  %Execution ;
```

### Program 2

You are only selecting a single column that will be read into `modified_CONTRAT`. There is a 1-1 mapping between variables in the `select` clause and `into` clause. A single `case` statement will still only pass to its corresponding value in the `into` clause. For what you are trying to do, I recommend using a data step instead.

```
data _null_;
    set sashelp.vtable;
    where     libname IN ('LS', 'KO') 
          AND memname IN ('CONTRAT', 'TCHOBQ');

    if(libname = 'LS' AND memname = 'CONTRAT') 
        then call symputx('modified_CONTRAT', datepart(modate));
        
    else if(libname = 'KO' AND memname = 'TCHOBQ') 
        then call symputx('modified_TCHOBQ', datepart(modate));
run;
```